# using amazons search not working

Tags: php, api, web-services

I have made a function that uses keywords like "Dell laptop x500" or something and it is trying to search for it. I did a hacky way of just adding it to the keywords search url, but it will give me different results compared to if i typed the text in the search box and pressed submit. Then it grabs the first results link back. Sometimes this works correctly and sometimes it does not.

```
function getAmazonLink($keywords){
        $keywords = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "%20", $keywords);
        $link = "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=$keywords";
        //return $link;
        $content = getContents($link);
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML($content);
        $as = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
        foreach ( $as as $a){
            if($a->parentNode->nodeName == 'h3'){
                if($a->parentNode->getAttribute('class') == 'newaps'){
                    if($a->parentNode->parentNode->getAttribute('id') == 'result_0'){

                        return $a->getAttribute('href');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $link;
```

Comment: Amazon profiles you. If you search for something it gives results tailored to what it thinks you will like. If I search for something  I get results tailored to what I might like. If a cookieless, unknown IP does a search then Amazon simply returns a general 'best guess'.

Comment: anyway to get around this? thanks for the comment

Comment: What do you mean "get around it"? Your results are personalized based on you, the results of someone generic are not personalized to anyone since they're not associated with an account. That's the only possible behavior that makes sense.

Comment: @sphanley of course there is a workaround! Open a new browser tab, go to Amazon, and do the search there. :I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon, like many other online stores, will tailor the search results based on your account's purchase/search history. Since your webapp isn't using a logged in Amazon account, it is getting results which aren't tailored to anyone's account history. In the comments you asked if there is a way to "work around this", but there's nothing to work around -- it's giving you valid results, just not ones which are tailored to a specific person's Amazon account. This is the expected result, not a bug.